# mussh no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: ssh, sudo

Using MUSSH on remote machine to execute a bash script

```
$ mussh -a -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -d -H mas-hostfile -c 'bash script.sh' -m2
sudo: unable to resolve host hostname
aurelien@000.000.000: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

If I directly ssh one of the machine and execute the script, all things goes correctly.

Comment: If I modify the command line by:  mussh -a -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -d -H mas-hostfile -c 'bash-s < ~/script.sh' -m2  . The trouble stay the same

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `mussh` to ask `ssh` to allocate a terminal using the `-o` option with `RequestTTY` value, e.g.,

```
mussh -o RequestTTY=yes -a -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -d -H mas-hostfile -c 'bash script.sh' -m2
```

If you used `ssh` directly, you could use its `-t` option, but `mussh` uses `-t` for a different purpose (and does not pass *that* to `ssh`):

> **`-t`**
>          Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based   programs on a remote machine, which can be
>            very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple `-t`
>            options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
>
> **`RequestTTY`**
>          Specifies whether to request a pseudo-tty for the session.  The
>            argument may be one of: *`no`* (never request a TTY), *`yes`*
>            (always request a TTY when standard input is a TTY), *`force`*
>            (always request a TTY) or *`auto`* (request a TTY when opening a
>            login session).  This option mirrors the `-t` and `-T` flags for
>            [ssh(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1).

Further reading:

- [mussh - MUltihost SSH](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mussh)
- [ssh -- OpenSSH SSH  client (remote login program)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1)
- [ssh_config  -- OpenSSH SSH client configuration files](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE)

Comment: With that command line I get: command-line line 0: missing argument.

Comment: I have modify your line by mussh -o RequestTT=yes -a -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -d -H hostfile -c 'bash script.sh' -m2   but it continue to says: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: you could use the `-v` option to see what is actually passed to `ssh`, to get more information.

Comment: Authenticated aurelien@...: debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
aurelien@...: debug1: channel 0: new [/tmp/ssh-aurelien@...]
aurelien@...: debug1: channel 1: new [client-session]
aurelien@...: debug1: Entering interactive session.
aurelien@...: debug1: pledge: id
aurelien@...: debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
aurelien@...: debug1: Sending environment.
aurelien@...: debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
aurelien@...: debug1: Sending command: bash
aurelien@...: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Comment: End of the debug output                                                            a@: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
a@: debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 1 rtype exit-status reply 0
a@: debug1: channel 1: free: client-session, nchannels 2
a@: debug1: channel 0: free: /tmp/ssh-a@, nchannels 1
a@: debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
a@: debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
a@: Transferred: sent 2700, received 3104 bytes, in 0.7 seconds
a@: Bytes per second: sent 3614.0, received 4154.7
a@: debug1: Exit status 1
DEBUG: Removing keys from agent
DEBUG: Stopping Agent

Comment: So with that command the script does not execute and keep the same error.

Comment: with that command without the = the error is not anymore and it does not execute the script too.

Comment: @ThomasDickey can we use mussh to connect to multiple servers which have the same password using the password?

Comment: Not according to the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mussh)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have solve the trouble! (after hours and fight)

Here is the full working code [ https://github.com/aurelien-git/MAS ]

*The solution was not to use RequestTTY*

**But to had the authorized_keys in the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys**

Now the command can be load normaly

```
mussh -a -i /home/aurelien/.ssh/id_rsa -d -H mas-hostfile -C 'update.sh' -m2
```

and much more ;-)

Comment: How were you able to ssh before, if the key was not not in the `authorized_keys` file?

Comment: the authorized_keys was in the /home/user/.ssh/ directory

Comment: I would have preferred a solution that works without being root and just use sudo to not do https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/V2V_Guide/Preperation_Before_the_P2V_Migration-Enable_Root_Login_over_SSH.html